# Pager Sliding TabStrip in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I would like to use **Pager Sliding TabStrip** in my project.[Pager Sliding Tapstrip](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/) is there for android. Can we define like this? I have taken  one scroll view, added subviews on it for tables and take one uivew, added buttons as subviews and added uilabel as subview for tabstrip . While using the scrollview means dragging the scrollview, the tabsrip has to be moved.I have been stuck to this concept and i am not getting any idea to solve this issue.  How do i get this concept? Please give any idea to me anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use UIPageControl for this ?

From Apple example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795

And to have a custom UIPageControl, like this https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl .

Comment: I have also used page control but It is not helped to me. I am not able to find any method When i drag the scrolleview. If i find that method i can do. The UIScrolviewDelegate(- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;,- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;) methods are there but those are not related my question. I want like this method -(void)scrollViewMoveDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView which is not uiscrollviewdelegate method

Answer (score 1):

You can try [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) to manage your tabs.

I'm not sure how many tabs do you have. If you have many tabs and you add all tables into the scrollView at the beginning time, the performance and memory usage would be really bad.

So you'd better reuse controller and views for your tabs. If you use `UIScrollView` and manage them by yourself, what you can do is calculate current page according to the `contentOffset`, and load the current page, previous page and next page. Because three pages is enough to cover what user will see. However the better solution is using `UIPageViewController`, it will deal with `contentOffset` and pagination, what your need to do is just provide previous controller and next controller according to current controller. Then update your tab view according to current controller.

**EDIT:**

BTW, if by "the tabstrip has to be moved" you mean when you drag the scrollView, your tabstrip moves as well, that's because you added your tabstrip to the scrollView. What you need to do is add it to the root view, and the scrollView and the tabstrip should be siblings rather than parent and child.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing application which required same features as asked by you.
I am using SHViewPageController. You can find it from following link.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/shviewpagerexample

I hope it will help you. Thanks.

Comment: It's fine but when i drag or swipe the page is disappearing and another page is appearing at same time and red indicator also same thing. My requirement is, when i drag any page, no need to disappear and appear another page. It has to be looked like moving like scrollview and for red indicator also.

Comment: You can create UIView for different screens and just add that into UIScrollview. Your logic will be different into each custom view class.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you....
you can change the tab at top or bottom. also it has got some nice customizations
https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager